# How to total up two different dropdown selection on jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, styles

I was wondering if it’s possible to combine & total up two different selection to display on `total button` below? I had inserted calculation on each selection. when a user selected the QTY will auto sum up and display on "Total button" but I managed to display only one selection.is there any possible to sum up two different selections and display the total on the button?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#meatroll").change(function() {
    var product = $(this).find(":selected").val();

    event.preventDefault();
    var x = parseInt($(".product").val());

    var total1 = x * "7.50";
    alert("Total:" + "$" + total1);
    $('.cow').html("Total:" + "$" + total1);
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#burger").change(function() {
    var product2 = $(this).find(":selected").val();

    event.preventDefault();
    var z = parseInt($(".product2").val());

    var total2 = z * "1.20";
    alert("Total:" + "$" + total2);
    $('.cow').html("Total:" + "$" + total2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
     <p> Burger...........QTY :
        <select id="burger" class="product2">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="60">60</option>
          <option value="70">70</option>
          <option value="80">80</option>
          <option value="90">90</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
        </select></P>

    <p> Meat Roll...... QTY:
        <select id="meatroll" class="product">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="60">60</option>
          <option value="70">70</option>
          <option value="80">80</option>
          <option value="90">90</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
        </select> 
      </P>
  </label>

<label><button class="cow">TOTAL :</button></label>
```

How to get the value or text from the total up?

Comment: You mean to want to combine 2 methods into one then sum total from them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it in this simple way

```js
 var sumTotal = function(){
     var totalProduct = parseInt($("#meatroll").find(":selected").val()) * 7.50;
     
     var totalProduct2 = parseInt($("#burger").find(":selected").val()) * 1.2;
     
     $('.cow').html("Total:" +"$"+ (totalProduct +  totalProduct2));
    };
    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".qty").change(function(){
       event.preventDefault();
       sumTotal();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
     <p> Burger...........QTY :
        <select id="burger" class="product2 qty">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="60">60</option>
          <option value="70">70</option>
          <option value="80">80</option>
          <option value="90">90</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
              </select></P>



     <p> Meat Roll...... QTY:
        <select id="meatroll" class="product qty">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="60">60</option>
          <option value="70">70</option>
          <option value="80">80</option>
          <option value="90">90</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
              </select> 
              </P>
  </label>
            
<label><button class="cow">TOTAL :</button></label>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Tan Nam Wu

Answer (score 2):

Try this, simply add span tag within button and add your value and update it.

JavaScript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#meatroll").change(function(){
        var product = $(this).val();
        var x = parseInt($(".product").val());        

        var total1 = x * "7.50" ;
        alert("Total:" +"$"+ total1);           
        addToTotal(total1);

    });

    $("#burger").change(function(){
        var product2 = $(this).val();
        var z = parseInt($(".product2").val());        

        var total2 = z * "1.20" ;
        alert("Total:" +"$"+ total2);   

        addToTotal(total2);
   });

   function addToToal(t){
       var total = parseInt($("#total").html);
       $("#total").html(total+t);
   }
});
```

HTML code

```
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label>
         <p> Burger...........QTY :
        <select id="burger" class="product2">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="60">60</option>
          <option value="70">70</option>
          <option value="80">80</option>
          <option value="90">90</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
              </select></P>



         <p> Meat Roll...... QTY:
        <select id="meatroll" class="product">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="60">60</option>
          <option value="70">70</option>
          <option value="80">80</option>
          <option value="90">90</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
              </select> 
              </P>
  </label>

<label><button class="cow">TOTAL :<span id="total"></span></button></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get the values of both dropdowns, calculate the price of each, add them together and display them. You can combine the selectors to run the same code for both dropdowns.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#meatroll, #burger").change(function() {
    var meatroll = parseInt($("#meatroll").val());
    var burger = parseInt($("#burger").val());
    var total = meatroll * 7.50 + burger * 1.20;
    var product = $(this).find(":selected").val();

    alert("Total:" + "$" + total);
    $('.cow').html("Total:" + "$" + total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
     <p> Burger...........QTY :
        <select id="burger" class="product2">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="60">60</option>
          <option value="70">70</option>
          <option value="80">80</option>
          <option value="90">90</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
        </select></P>

    <p> Meat Roll...... QTY:
        <select id="meatroll" class="product">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="60">60</option>
          <option value="70">70</option>
          <option value="80">80</option>
          <option value="90">90</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
        </select> 
      </P>
  </label>

<label><button class="cow">TOTAL :</button></label>
```

If you want a more general solution, you can give all your dropdowns a class, put the price in a `data-price` attribute, and use a loop.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".product").change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".product").each(function() {
      var quantity = $(this).val();
      var price = $(this).data("price");
      total += quantity * price;
    });

    alert("Total:" + "$" + total);
    $('.cow').html("Total:" + "$" + total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
     <p> Burger...........QTY :
        <select id="burger" class="product" data-price="1.20">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="60">60</option>
          <option value="70">70</option>
          <option value="80">80</option>
          <option value="90">90</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
        </select></P>

    <p> Meat Roll...... QTY:
        <select id="meatroll" class="product" data-price="7.50">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="60">60</option>
          <option value="70">70</option>
          <option value="80">80</option>
          <option value="90">90</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
        </select> 
      </P>
  </label>

<label><button class="cow">TOTAL :</button></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#meatroll, #burger").change(function() {

    var total = (parseInt($("#meatroll").val(), 10) * 7.50 )+ (parseInt($("#burger").val(), 10) * 1.20);
    $('.cow').html("Total:   " + "$" + total );
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>


<label>
         <p> Burger...........QTY :
        <select id="burger" class="product2">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="60">60</option>
          <option value="70">70</option>
          <option value="80">80</option>
          <option value="90">90</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
        </select></P>

        <p> Meat Roll...... QTY:
        <select id="meatroll" class="product">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="60">60</option>
          <option value="70">70</option>
          <option value="80">80</option>
          <option value="90">90</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
        </select> 
      </P>
  </label>

<label><button class="cow">TOTAL :</button></label>



</body>
</html>
```

Jquery allow us to specify any number of selectors to combine into a single result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to select disparate elements. Also, the parseInt() function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix.

Comment: Noted Thanks @Jobelle